# Provide a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ like $\beta$ such that the representation matrix of $T$ with respect to $\beta$ becomes identity

Tags: tensors

Assume that $T \in L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ is a $2$-tensor in $\mathbb R^2$ and the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2\\
        2 & -1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Provide a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ like $\beta$ such that the representation matrix of $T$ with respect to $\beta$ becomes identity.

Note : My problem is that i don't understand whats the meaning of the "matrix representation of a $k$-tensor". And i've got no clue of solving this problem.

Comment: Does $L^2(\Bbb R^2)$ mean the space of bilinear functionals on $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @BobbieD it means all of the $2$-tensors on $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: 2-tensor is an ambiguous term.  What do you mean by 2-tensor?

Comment: @BobbieD for example, the dual space is $1$-tensor.  A $k$-tensor is a function which takes $k$ vectors and returns a scalar(in this case, a real number)

Comment: you can't because this matrix has a negative eigenvalue

Answer (score 1):

The matrix representation of the tensor $T:\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal B$ is the matrix $A$ such that, for all $u,v\in \Bbb R^2$, $$T(u,v) = [u]_{\mathcal B}^TA[v]_{\mathcal B}$$ where $[u]_{\mathcal B}$, $[v]_{\mathcal B}$ are the column matrices with the coordinates of $u$ and $v$ written with respect to $\mathcal B$.

Example: Let $T(u,v) = u_1v_2 + 2u_2v_1$.  With respect to the standard basis the matrix which represents $T$ is $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$